# Find a position vector $r(t)$ at time $t$ (word problem).

Tags: vectors

A particle traveling in a straight line is located at point $(9,8,-9)$ and has speed $5$ at time $t=0$. The particle moves toward the point $(4,6,6)$ with constant acceleration $(-5,-2,15)$. Find its position vector $r⃗(t)$ at time $t$.

So, it's obvious I don't know how to start this problem. I was thinking since it gave me the constant acceleration $(-5,-2,15)$, I could find its integral? But I am thrown off by the particle moving between different points. Can you walk  me through this? Thank you.

Comment: Break the problem into the three orthogonal directions and solve each separately.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** When the exercise says that the acceleration is constant and equal to $(-5,-2,15)$, they are saying that the straight line is in the same direction that $(4,6,6)-(9,8,-9)$, and nothing more. Since the motion is in a straight line, we have that ${\bf r}(t) = {\bf p}+t{\bf v}$. You also know that ${\bf r}(0)$ and that ${\bf r}'(0) = {\bf v}$ is in the direction of $(5,-2,15)$, satisfying $\|{\bf v}\| = 5$. With this you can find ${\bf p}$ and ${\bf v}.$

Comment: how come the acceleration is the second derivative and not the first?

Comment: $\bf r$: position.

$\bf r'$: velocity.

$\bf r''$: acceleration.

Comment: @Elsa I have rephrased my answer in hopes of clarifying stuff.